# To move an object forward an exact distance and then stop

Tags: unity, animation

I am using this script below to move an animated object in unity with no root-motion. it simply walks across the terrain and has a timer so it waits 60 seconds until starting.

```
void Update ()
{
    if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > 60)
    {
        transform.Translate(0, 0, Time.deltaTime);
    }
}
```

I want the object to travel a certain distance or certain amount of steps and then stop at an exact point and stay there, is there a simple way to add to the above code to do this? does it entail xyz position reached maybe?

Comment: Did you look at the Vector3.MoveTowards method? It handles exactly this case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can do this more simply:

```
public class WaitThenMoveToTarget : MonoBehaviour {

    // Set your parameters in the Inspector.
    public float waitSeconds = 60f;
    public Vector3 targetOffset = Vector3.forward * 10f;
    public float speed = 1f;

    // Make Start a coroutine that begins 
    // as soon as our object is enabled.
    IEnumerator Start() {

         // First, wait our defined duration.
         yield return new WaitForSeconds(waitSeconds);

         // Then, pick our destination point offset from our current location.
         Vector3 targetPosition = transform.position + targetOffset;

         // Loop until we're within Unity's vector tolerance of our target.
         while(transform.position != targetPosition) {

              // Move one step toward the target at our given speed.
              transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(
                    transform.position,
                    targetPosition,
                    speed * Time.deltaTime
               );

               // Wait one frame then resume the loop.
               yield return null;
         }

         // We have arrived. Ensure we hit it exactly.
         transform.position = targetPosition;
    }
}
```

Comment: excuse the long delay, but have just got back to this now. The above code works very well for me (an 'i' missing in transform.position). Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for the spellcheck! Fixed. :) Glad it worked for your needs.

Answer (score 0):

First you will want to define a start and end position in your scene. Create `GameObjects` in the editor to place at the start and end positions of your movement path, and drag and drop them into the `startObject` and `endObject` fields in the script below.

Then you can interpolate between the two positions using the `Vector3.Lerp()` function ([more details here](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3.Lerp.html)).

The code below linearly moves your object from `startPos` to `endPos` over `moveDuration` seconds.

```
public Transform startObject;
public Transform endObject;

[Tooltip("How long the movement will take in seconds.")]
public float moveDuration = 1;

[Tooltip("The delay in seconds before movement starts.")]
public float startDelay = 60;

bool isMoving = false;
bool hasMoved = false;



void Update() {
    // if it is time to move, and this object is not moving, and hasn't moved yet
    if (Time.timeSinceLevelLoad > startDelay && !isMoving && !hasMoved) {
        // start moving (this moves the current object from startObject.position to endObject.position over moveDuration seconds)
        StartCoroutine(Move(startObject.position, endObject.position, moveDuration));
    }
}


IEnumerator Move(Vector3 startPos, Vector3 endPos, float duration){
    // Record that we are about to start moving
    isMoving = true;
    // timeElapsed will incresase from 0 to duration over the course of the while loop
    var timeElapsed = 0f;
    while(timeElapsed < duration){
        // lerp (linearly interpolate) the position of this object between startPos and endPos
        // Use (timeElapsed / duration) to control how close it is to the startPos vs the endPos
        transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, timeElapsed/duration);
        // Wait a frame and record that time has elapsed 
        yield return new WaitForEndOfFrame();
        timeElapsed += Time.deltaTime;
    }    
    // Make sure that the object ends at the correct endPos
    transform.position = Vector3.Lerp(startPos, endPos, timeElapsed/duration);
    // Record that we are not moving anymore and that this object has moved
    isMoving = false;
    hasMoved = true;
}
```